# Как сравнить разницу между текущей и будущей датой с точностью до месяца?

Tags: javascript, jquery, дата, datetime

Есть задачка, в которой необходимо сравнить текущую дату с заданной в будущем с точностью до месяца включительно и определить разницу в количестве месяцев между датами и соответственно столько раз кликнуть на кнопку.

Т.е., к примеру, сегодняшняя дата: *15-06-2019*, будущая: *07-09-2019* и надо прокликать (посчитать клики) ровно до того момента, когда получим *01-10-2019*

Какой это месяц и сколько в нем дней (28,29,30 или 31) и текущий год (високосный или нет) нужно обязательно учитывать.

Вот, какие сделал наработки и дальше ступор..

```js
var now = new Date();
var dateNow = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() + 1, now.getDate());
dateNow.setDate(1);
var future = new Date("08/09/2019");
var futureTime = future.getTime();
var dateTime = dateNow.getTime();
if (futureTime > dateTime) {
  $(".btn").click();
  dateTime += (86400000 * 30);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного не понял точные условия подсчёта, но предлагаю подсчитать количество месяцев заранее, а потом это число раз можно и по кнопке покликать.

```js
function monthDiff(start, end) {
    let months = 12*(end.getYear() - start.getYear()); // 12 месяцев на каждый год
    months -= start.getMonth(); // сколько месяцев до начала
    months += end.getMonth(); // сколько ещё осталось до конца

    return months > 0 ? months : 0;
}

let now = new Date();
let future = new Date("2020-08-27");
let diff = monthDiff(now, future);
console.log(diff);

let clicks = [];
for(let i = 0; i < diff; ++i) clicks.push(`click ${i+1}`);
console.log(clicks.join('; '));

// Получим первое число следующего месяца:
let finalDate = new Date;
finalDate.setTime(future.getTime());
if (future.getDate() !== 1) {
  finalDate.setMonth(future.getMonth()+1);
  finalDate.setDate(1);
}
console.log(finalDate.toLocaleDateString())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*На самом деле, точный расчёт зависит только от точной постановки задачи, что именно считать месяцем.*

---

Неплохим решением будет использовать предназначенную для этого библиотеку:

```js
let now = new Date();
let future = new Date("2020-08-27");
let diff = moment(future).diff(moment(now), 'month');
console.log(diff)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: "На самом деле, точный расчёт зависит только от точной постановки задачи, что именно считать месяцем."
да, есть нюанс, что нужно точно включить текущий месяц в подсчет, даже если это последний день месяца, но, если текущий совпадает с будущим, то не засчитывать. Т.е. если сегодня 1 или 31 июля, а будущая дата - 8 сентября, то июль считается за месяц, а если сегодня 1 сентября, то уже нет. С `moment` есть момент, что идет подсчет чистых месяцев. Если август и сентябрь можно сравнить `isSame`, то как быть с 1 и 31 июля, чтобы их посчитали одинаково?